# Provide Angular module

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-module

I'm currently developing an Angular 4 module that needs to be imported into a larger Angular 4 single-page application. The module bootstraps a single, widget-like component that grants access to other functionalities of the module.

Page and module are separate projects developed by different development teams and there are no interfaces between them. They're both developed using Angular CLI.

**Question:** What's an easy way for me to provide the complete module, so it can be embedded into the page by the other team?

Ideas I've had so far:

- I don't mind sharing the full project. So obviously they could copy all relevant code to their project. This seems extremely messy, though, and requires dependencies to be merged manually.
- Publishing the module as an NPM package would solve these problems, but for legal reasons I'm not allowed to push to a public repository and shy the effort to set up a private one just for this usecase.

Bonus points for any solution that only requires the production built module (as aot-compiled js-files)!

Comment: You may find this discussion interesting: [https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6510](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6510)

Answer (score 1):

In their package.json they could directly reference your git release branch,

"yourModule" : "git+https://yourepo.git#release/1.0"

[Reference here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for that tip! Reading through that reference [I also learned](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bundleddependencies) that you can package a project as a tgz archive with `npm pack` and install a tgz-packaged module with `npm install my-module-1.0.0.tgz`

Answer (score 0):

As Juli3n pointed out in his answer, NPM is really flexible when it comes to handle "non-standard" repositories. However, I underestimated the effort it takes to build a library package from an Angular CLI project.

The most efficient solution I've found for that is [ng-packagr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr). It creates a dedicated library project out of an existing Angular (CLI) project and requires only little configuration. A very good step-by-step tutorial can be found [on Medium](https://medium.com/@ngl817/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e).